# Unrecognized selector sent to instance On UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am parsing `JSON` and get the `value.Store` value as `NSString` and when I want to show on `UILabel` app crashes with

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b070470`

NSString *idvalue = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"id"];`
labl_id.text =idvalue;
NSLog(@"id value%@",idvalue);

output: id value 6
```

please let me know how to fix this
thanks

Comment: Not enough information.  What's the JSON content?  What's the unrecognized selector?

Comment: Check Class of jsonResponse, maybe it is not NSDictionary.
    NSStringFromClass([jsonResponse class]);

Comment: NSDictionary * jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error]; jsonresponse I am storing in Dictionary

Comment: which type of value you are storing in JSON.. is it string or anything else.

Comment: I am getting response from server and store response in NSDictionary and fetch from dictionary

Comment: Are you sure you get idvalue form jsonResponse? and that jsonResponse is not null?

Comment: NSJSONSerialization may return array of dictionaries.

Comment: yes I am getting idvalue from json response

Comment: yes I am getting array  of dictionary Vladz you are right

Comment: check what type of idvalue you are getting, maybe it isn't NSString.
Or use this  labl_id.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",idvalue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mb you get NSNumber

```
NSString *idvalue = [[jsonResponse valueForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
```